# Config server unable to reach git when application deployed in cloud foundry

Tags: spring, git, cloud, config, spring-cloud

I have deployed a config server service in Pivotal cloud foundry. 
My yml has the
 cloud
  config
   server
    git
      url: pointing to a public repo in our organization.
When I hit the url to access the config server through local host, the config server is able to reach the GIT repo and print out the test properties and its contents without any issues. But, the same application after pushing to cloud foundry, the url doesn't read/print any of the properties from the GIT repo. There is no indication of errors  in the logs. In fact log level is set to Trace. There is no indication of any firewall issues.
Can any one say why my config server service app is not able to reach git and read the properties file.

Comment: Though you say otherwise, it sounds like some kind of network issue. Can you make some other external network request from the same app?

Comment: The issue ended up being in our manifest.yml file.  We had env: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE set to native when it should have been "cloud" to match our application.yml.  Making that change solved our issue.   This exposed a firewall issue that we still working out.  The logs are showing connection issues due to the firewall but that is just an internal issue for us to work on.  The solution to the original question is to make sure SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE  is configured correctly.